# How to use SVG in FTL files

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I have a requirement that i need to read the SVG image in FTL file.and i want to change the svg icon image color in HTML or CSS

generally we to achieve this in angular we follow the following way. so i want the similar solution or any better suitable one.

```
 <svg width="36" height="36">
<image href="Imagepath" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"></image>
</svg>
```

or

```
<svg-icon [applyCss]="true" src="../../../../assets/img/icons/completed.svg" class="svgIconSidebar"></svg-icon>
```

while i am trying both ways above i am not able to get any image.
can anybody please suggest what is the correct approvach to achive my requirement.

Comment: sorry if I'm off-topic, but couldn't you manipulate your svg image with some javascript?